# How do you limit the number of results under a particular heading in a block custom agenda view?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

How do you limit the number of results under a particular heading in a block custom agenda view?

I use a custom agenda with several blocks. For example:

```
(defun tagstatus (tagName)
    "helper to make tags filter with preset TODO statuses"
    (concat "+" tagName "/!+TODO|+NEXT|+STARTED"))

(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
     '(("z" "custom agenda blocks"
        ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Today") (org-agenda-span 'day)))
         (tags (tagstatus "tag1") ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Tag 1 Items")))
         (tags (tagstatus "tag2") ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Tag 2 Items")))
        ))))
```

I would like to be able to limit the number of items that are shown under a given header. For example, limit "Tag 1 Items" to the top 5 TODOs that match that tagName. Is this possible? How?

I have looked at Limiting Agenda Items (https://orgmode.org/manual/Filtering_002flimiting-agenda-items.html), and **org-agenda-max-entries**; it seems simple enough to set that globally, but I don't understand how to integrate it into a block view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, so just a guess:

```el
   ...
   (tags (tagstatus "tag1") ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Tag 1 Items")
                             (org-agenda-max-entries 5)))
   ...
```

or maybe `org-agenda-max-tags` instead of `org-agenda-max-entries`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I tried, but for some reason it didn't work for me the first time I tried it. But this works to limit the results, exactly what I needed.